# Determining Serial Driver Supported Baud Rates

Tags: windows, drivers, serial-port, bitrate

How can I determine the baud rates supported by my serial driver?  My driver details (from the Device Manager) follow, but they do not seem very helpful.  I am writing an application that is crashing because I am apparently attempting to to set COM1 to an unsupported baud rate, so I need to know which baud rates the driver does support.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

> Driver files:
>
> C:\Windows\system32\drivers\serenum.sys
>
> C:\Windows\system32\drivers\serial.sys
>
> Provider: Microsoft Corporation File
>
> Version: 5.1.2600.5512 (xpsp.080413-2108)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serial.sys appears to support up to 115200bps (112.5kbps). Below that, it is determined by the device AFAIK.

Otherwise I think you'll have to look at [GetCommProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363259%28VS.85%29.aspx) for Win32 (Platform SDK) [serial communications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx), or the [SerialPort class](http://www.lvr.com/serport.htm#example_code) in .NET Framework v2.0+.